# Regex: match "group3.*group1" if group2 is not between groups 3 and 1

Tags: regex, python-3.x, regex-negation, regex-lookarounds

I'm using Python 3.4.
I have three groups:

```
g1 = 'g11|g12'
g2 = 'g21|g22'
g3 = 'g31|g32'
```

I want to match any instance of g3, followed by anything except g2, followed by g1.  Here are some strings on which I want to find a match:

```
'g31 anything or nothing g11'  
'g31g11'
EDIT:  ADDED:  'anything or nothing g31 g11 anything or nothing'
EDIT:  ADDED:  'anything or nothing g21 g31 g11 anything or nothing'
```

and here are some strings on which I do not want to find a match:

```
'g31 anything or nothing g21 anything or nothing g11'
'g31g21g11'
```

I tried:  `(g31|g32)(?=.*?(g11|g12))(?!.*?(g21|g22))`, which works for 
`'g31 g11'` and `'g31 g21 g11'` but fails if there is a g21 or g22 after g11, as in `'g31 g11 g21'`.

I've also tried `'(g31|g32).*?(g21|g22){0}.*?(g11|g22)'` which works for `'g31 g11'` and `'g31 g21 g11'` but not `'g31 g31 g21 g11'`.

The problem would be trivial if I could expect fixed width strings, e.g., `'g31 g11'` or `'g31 g21 g11'` and there are many solutions to such a problem on stackoverflow already.  Also, I could have presented this problem without groups but I want to avoid any solutions that use `[]`.

I hope that I won't be told that this isn't possible with regex but if it is, so be it.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
^.*?(?:g31|g32)(?!.*?(?:g21|g22)).*?(?:g11|g12).*$
```

Try this.See demo:

https://regex101.com/r/hI0qP0/9#python

Comment: @Kasra all answers are correct and are what OP expects

Comment: + My idea is similar to yours and @karthikmanchala, came up with `^.*g3[12](?:(?!g2[12]).)*g1[12].*` [see regex101](https://regex101.com/r/sL7mR6/1) and good to see you vks :)

Comment: Hey @Jonny5 where have u been????its been long since i saw ur witty answers :) .............

Comment: I'm not too far away from your country right now :] but too far to have some chai :}

Comment: These only work when the groups' elements are disjoint.  (I.e., `g[ij] =/= g[mn] for all pairs i,j,m,n in [1,2].`)  What I'm really after is the case where `g3 = a|b|c`, `g2 = a|b|c|d`, and `g1 = c.`  This is still a case of the original post, albeit a strange one, right?  Can this be done?  Also, should I post another question with these criteria?

Comment: @epistemicFUN guess you should post a new question .accept one of the answers here,coz it would need a new approach or a hell lot of tweaking

Answer (score 1):

It is entirely possible.. You can use the following regex:

```
 g3\d+(?:(?!g2).)*g1\d+
```

See [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/bU6nB9/2)

Comment: Try `g31 a bunch of anything or nothing g21 a bunch of anything or nothing g41`

Comment: @Kasra question is only for group3 and group1 not group 4 or something else.. I think this answer is to the point and without extra assumptions..

Comment: The question is somehow ambiguity! but OP doesn't said its not about other groups, OP said *I want to match any instance of g3* so your answer is not a general way!

Comment: @Kasra Its `I want to match any instance of g3, followed by anything except g2, followed by g1` and not `I want to match any instance of g3`...

Comment: Indeed and doesn't said all of my texts starts with `g3` or I'm just dealing with that instances.anyway i just noted that ;)